# Get Promise Value (axios inside Axios) and set to Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have 2 axios functions, one is to return a list of currency names and the other is to get the value of the said currencies. I need to get corresponding value of the currency unto a hook.

```
[currencies, setCurrencies] = useState([]);

getCurrencyNames = () => 
  axios({
    method: `get`,
    url: `${url}/getCurrencies`
  }).then(r =>
    setCurrencies(r.data.map(currency => {
      return {
        name: currency,
        value: getCurrencyValue(currency)
      }
    }))
  );

getCurrencyValue = async (currency) => {
  const data = await axios({
    method: `get`,
    url: `${url}/getValue/?from=PHP&to=${currency}`   
  }).then(r => r.data)

  return data;
}
```

what should return is the currencies hook being filled with objects such as this:

```
{
  name: "USD",
  value: 0.020
}
```

but the objects returned like this:

```
{
  name: "USD",
  value: Promise
}
```

I've also tried setting the hook into the getCurrencyValue like this:

```
getCurrencyValue = async (currency) => {
  axios({
    method: `get`,
    url: `${url}/getValue/?from=PHP&to=${currency}`   
  }).then(r => 
    setCurrencies([
      ...currencies, 
      name: currency,
      value: r.data
    ])
  )
}
```

but what happens is that only the last one is set inside the hook

Comment: put a await before getCurrencyValue(currency)

Comment: [Async functons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) always return a promise. So you need to do `await getCurrencyValue(currency)`

Comment: I get an "unexpected reserved word 'await'" error when I put an await in front of the getCurrencyValue.

Comment: What are you returning here??
then(r =>
    setCurrencies(r.data.map(currency => {  <=Here
      return {
        name: currency,
        value: getCurrencyValue(currency)
      }
    }))

setCurrency does not return any value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [currencies, setCurrencies] = useState([]);

  async function getCurrencyValue(post) {
    const data = await axios({
      method: `get`,
      url: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`
    }).then((r) => ({
      post,
      user: r.data
    }));

    return data;
  }

  function getCurrencyNames() {
    return axios({
      method: `get`,
      url: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`
    }).then((r) => {
      const res = Promise.all(
        r.data.map(async (currency) => {
          return {
            name: currency,
            value: await getCurrencyValue(currency)
          };
        })
      );
      return res;
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    (async function () {
      const data = await getCurrencyNames();
      console.log(data);
      console.log("fetched in useEffect");
      setCurrencies(data);
    })();
  }, []);

  return <></>;
}
export default App;
```

Here is the link https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-germain-8ie8j?file=/src/App.js

`Note: See in the console`

Comment: This has the answer that I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It is normal that it return a promise, you have to resolve it by puting await befor the call and make the map function async:

```
getCurrencyNames = () => 
 axios({
   method: `get`,
   url: `${url}/getCurrencies`
 }).then(r =>
   setCurrencies(r.data.map(async currency => {
   return {
    name: currency,
    value: await getCurrencyValue(currency)
  }
}))
);
```

Comment: I've tried this, but it resulted in a hook filled with empty objects. [Here](https://imgur.com/h1mWwBZ) is what returns